# Winforms Sql server database long running query

Tags: sql-server

We have a very old vb.net winforms application which uses sql server as its database. Our application is such that we have to store changes in various modules in our system eg. CustomerAccident, CustomerAdmission etc and also insert a brief description and lots of other guids to establish relation between different type of events happening into our dailyReporting table(i.e data is stored in a very normalized way). When we display data from this reporting table we have created a view to help us to give a de-normalized form of the data which we then display in the customer record.

As you can imagine for few of our customers this reporting table has now more than a million rows. now every time clients try to view the Customer record because the query has to go through so many rows it is taking a lot of time for the query to run and in some cases blocking few tables which is causing problems for other users.

To solve this we were thinking of creating a whole new reporting db and storing the information there in a de-normalized form and filling various tables there in the same as  we would in the view just by using triggers.

I know this might be  bit vague question to ask but i am looking for other ideas if anyone else had experience with this situation.

The following is the sql query being used to get the information

```
exec sp_executesql N'
         SELECT 
            ''Customer Report'' AS type
        ,   CASE --Record Type
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 12 = 12 
                    OR cv_customerDailyReport.type & 19 = 19 
                    OR cv_customerDailyReport.type & 65 = 65 THEN
                    ''ABC''
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 54 = 54 THEN
                    ''CDE''
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 96 = 96 THEN
                    ''REW''
            ELSE 
                cv_customerDailyReport.Description
            END AS ReportType
        ,   CASE -- SUB TYPE
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 258 = 258 THEN
                    ''QWE''
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 321 = 321  THEN
                    ''RTY''
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 1 = 1 THEN
                    ''AGX''
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 8 = 8 THEN
                    ''CTE''
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 16 = 16 THEN
                    ''TYU''
            ELSE 
                ''other''
            END AS subtype
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.customerDailyRecord AS ''guid''
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.ActionDate
        ,   COALESCE(userTable.name,''exStaff'') as ''By''
        ,   CASE 
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=0 THEN 
                    (''Unsure / NA'')
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=1 THEN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') THEN
                                    (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') 
                            ELSE ''Improved'' 
                            END
                    )
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=258 THEN 
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') THEN
                                    (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') 
                            ELSE 
                                ''Not change'' 
                            END
                    )
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=3 THEN
                    (
                        SELECT 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') THEN
                                    (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') 
                            ELSE 
                                ''Bad'' 
                            END
                    )
            END AS ''Improvement''
        ,   CASE
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 258 = 258 THEN
                    convert(varchar,cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValue) + '' '' + chemist.Name -- + '', '' + cv_customerDailyReport.observationText 
                    + ''  '' + 
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN (cv_customerDailyReport.comment<>'''' or cv_customerDailyReport.comment<>null) THEN
                                (
                                    SELECT 
                                        CASE 
                                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Feedbackquestion'') THEN 
                                                (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Feedbackquestion'') 
                                        ELSE 
                                            ''Please comment'' 
                                        END
                                ) 
                                + '' - ''+          
                                (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=0 THEN 
                                            (''Unsure / NA'')
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=1 THEN 
                                            (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    CASE 
                                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') THEN
                                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') 
                                                    ELSE 
                                                        ''Improved'' 
                                                    END
                                            )
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=258 THEN 
                                            (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    CASE 
                                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') THEN
                                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') 
                                                    ELSE 
                                                        ''Unchanged'' 
                                                    END
                                            )
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=3 THEN 
                                            (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    CASE 
                                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') THEN                                       
                                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') 
                                                    ELSE 
                                                        ''Deteriorated'' 
                                                    END
                                            )
                                    END
                                ) 
                                + '' - '' + cv_customerDailyReport.comment
                        ELSE 
                            '''' 
                        END
                    )
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 321 = 321 
                    AND cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValue <> 0 THEN
                    -- measurment
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (MeasurementType.StatusFlags & 16 = 16 ) THEN 
                            cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValueAndType 
                            + '' - '' + convert(varchar,COALESCE(CONVERT(INT,cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValue),0)) 
                            + ''/'' + convert(varchar,COALESCE(CONVERT(INT,cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValue2),0)) 
                    ELSE 
                        cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValueAndType 
                        + '' - '' + convert(varchar,COALESCE(cv_customerDailyReport.measurementValue,0)) 
                    END
                    + ''  '' + 
                    (
                        CASE 
                            WHEN(cv_customerDailyReport.comment <> '''' 
                                or cv_customerDailyReport.comment<>null) THEN
                                (
                                    SELECT 
                                        CASE 
                                            WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Feedbackquestion'') THEN 
                                                (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Feedbackquestion'') 
                                        ELSE 
                                            ''Do you think the person’s quality of life has improved?'' 
                                        END
                                ) 
                                + '' - '' + 
                                (
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=0 THEN 
                                            (''Unsure / NA'')
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=1 THEN 
                                            (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    CASE 
                                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') THEN                                           
                                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') 
                                                    ELSE 
                                                        ''Improved'' 
                                                    END
                                            )
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=258 THEN 
                                            (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    CASE 
                                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') THEN                                       
                                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') 
                                                    ELSE 
                                                        ''Unchanged'' 
                                                    END
                                            )
                                        WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=3 THEN 
                                            (
                                                SELECT 
                                                    CASE 
                                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') THEN                                       
                                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') 
                                                    ELSE 
                                                        ''Deteriorated'' 
                                                    END
                                            )
                                    END
                                ) 
                                + '' - '' + cv_customerDailyReport.comment
                        ELSE
                            '''' 
                        END
                    )
                WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.type & 485 = 485 THEN
                    (
                        SELECT top 1 
                            CASE 
                                WHEN pain = 1 THEN 
                                    ''DER = True'' + '' - ''
                            ELSE
                                ''''
                            END
                            +
                            CASE 
                                WHEN woundGrade = 1 THEN 
                                    ''Grade : '' + ''Ungraded'' + '' - ''
                                WHEN woundGrade = 258 THEN 
                                    ''Grade : '' +''Grade 1'' + '' - '' 
                                WHEN woundGrade = 3 THEN 
                                    ''Grade : '' +''Grade 258'' + '' - '' 
                                WHEN woundGrade = 321 THEN 
                                    ''Grade : '' +''Grade 3'' + '' - '' 
                                WHEN woundGrade = 5 THEN 
                                    ''Grade : '' +''Grade 321'' + '' - '' 
                            ELSE
                                ''''
                            END 
                            +
                            CASE 
                                WHEN NullIF(Location , '''') IS NOT NULL THEN 
                                    ''Location : '' + Location + '' - ''
                            ELSE
                                ''''    
                            END
                            +
                            '' Width : '' + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR ,woundWidth),''N/A'')  + '' - '' + 
                            '' Lenth : ''  + ISNULL(convert(VARCHAR ,woundLength), ''N/A'')
                        FROM
                            customerWoundHistory
                        WHERE
                            customerWoundHistoryId = cv_customerDailyReport.customerDailyRecord
                    )
            ELSE
                cv_customerDailyReport.observationText
                + ''  '' + 
                (
                    CASE 
                        WHEN (cv_customerDailyReport.comment <> '''' 
                            or cv_customerDailyReport.comment<>null) THEN
                            (
                                SELECT 
                                    CASE 
                                        WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Feedbackquestion'') THEN 
                                            (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Feedbackquestion'') 
                                    ELSE 
                                        ''Do you think quality has improved?'' 
                                    END
                            ) 
                            + '' - ''+          
                            (
                                CASE 
                                    WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=0 THEN 
                                        (''Unsure / NA'')
                                    WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=5 THEN 
                                        (
                                            SELECT 
                                                CASE 
                                                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') THEN                                         
                                                        (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input2'') 
                                                ELSE 
                                                    ''Improved'' 
                                                END
                                        )
                                    WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=258 THEN 
                                        (
                                            SELECT 
                                                CASE 
                                                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') THEN                                        
                                                        (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input3'') 
                                                ELSE 
                                                    ''Unchanged'' 
                                                END
                                        )
                                    WHEN cv_customerDailyReport.Improvement=31 THEN 
                                        (
                                            SELECT 
                                                CASE 
                                                    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') THEN                                        
                                                    (SELECT value FROM optionsTable WHERE name=''Input4'') 
                                                ELSE 
                                                    ''Deteriorated'' 
                                                END
                                        )
                                END
                            ) 
                            + '' - '' + cv_customerDailyReport.comment
                    ELSE 
                        '''' 
                    END
                )
            END AS ''action''
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.comments AS ''text''
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.timestamp
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.Status
        ,   CASE 
                WHEN(attachmentTable.category=''QWE'') THEN 
                    1 
            ELSE 
                0 
            END AS ''hasattachment''
        ,   CASE 
                WHEN(cv_customerDailyReport.type & @sign = @sign) THEN 
                    1 
            ELSE 
                0 
            END AS ''hasBeenLookedAt''
        ,   CASE 
                WHEN(cv_customerDailyReport.type & 65536 = 65536) THEN 
                    1 
            ELSE 
                0 
            END AS ''IsAvailable''
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.sourceSystem
        ,   cv_customerDailyReport.ADLIDs
        ,   CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, actionDate, completedDate) < 0 THEN
                    0
                ELSE
                    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, actionDate, completedDate)
                END AS Duration
        FROM
            cv_customerDailyReport 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN  userTable on cv_customerDailyReport.createdbyuser = userTable.guid
            LEFT OUTER JOIN chemist on cv_customerDailyReport.medicine = chemist.medication
            LEFT OUTER JOIN enumnerationTable as MeasurementType ON cv_customerDailyReport.measurementType = MeasurementType.guid 
            LEFT JOIN attachmentTable on attachmentTable.parentID=cv_customerDailyReport.customerDailyRecord and attachmentTable.category=''DailyAttachmentFile'' 
        WHERE 
            ActionDate <= getDate()
            AND cv_customerDailyReport.status IN (@completed, @completedAndPaid, @Void, @Cancelled, @authorised)
            AND cv_customerDailyReport.customer = @customer
            AND (
                    cv_customerDailyReport.ActionDate >= @FromDate 
                    OR cv_customerDailyReport.timestamp > @FromTimeStamp
                )
            AND (
                    cv_customerDailyReport.categoryDescription LIKE @filterText 
                    OR cv_customerDailyReport.observationText LIKE @filterText 
                    OR cv_customerDailyReport.comments LIKE @filterText 
                    OR chemist.Name LIKE @filterText
                )
            AND (
                    (
                        @maxAge = 0 AND cv_customerDailyReport.ActionDate >= @FromDate
                    ) 
                    OR  (
                            cv_customerDailyReport.ActionDate >= DATEADD(day, -@maxAge, @CurrentDate)
                        )
                )

        UNION

        SELECT 
            ''event'' AS type
        ,   CASE customerHistory.type
                WHEN 0 THEN 
                    ''UIO''
                WHEN 258 THEN 
                    ''DER''
                WHEN 3 THEN 
                    ''WER''
                WHEN 1 THEN
                    ''SDE''
            ELSE
                ''Diary''
            END AS subtype
        ,   ''event'' AS categoryType
        ,   customerHistory.guid AS ''guid''
        ,   customerHistory.dateStarted AS ActionDate
        ,   ISNULL  ((SELECT name FROM userTable WHERE individualCustomerHostory.lastupdatedbyuser = userTable.guid),''system'') AS ''By''
        ,   '''' AS ''Improvement''
        ,   customerHistory.comments AS ''action''
        ,   individualCustomerHostory.completedNotes AS ''text''
        ,   individualCustomerHostory.timestamp
        ,   individualCustomerHostory.status
        ,   CASE 
                WHEN(attachmentTable.category = ''DailyAttachmentFile'') THEN 
                    1 
            ELSE 
                0 
            END AS ''hasattachment''
        ,   '''' As ''hasBeenLookedAt''
        ,   '''' AS ''IsAvailable''
        ,   ''0'' AS sourceSystem
        ,   '''' AS Categoryids
        ,   '''' AS Duration
        FROM 
            customerHistory
            LEFT OUTER JOIN roomInfo on customerHistory.room = roomInfo.unit
            LEFT JOIN attachmentTable on attachmentTable.parentID=customerHistory.guid AND attachmentTable.category = ''DailyAttachmentFile''
        WHERE 
            customerHistory.customer = @customer
            AND (
                    customerHistory.lastUpdated >= @FromDate 
                    OR individualCustomerHostory.timestamp > @FromTimeStamp
                )
            AND (
                    (
                        roomInfo.shortName LIKE @filterText 
                        OR roomInfo.fullName LIKE @filterText
                    )
                    OR customerHistory.type > 0
                )
            AND (
                    (
                        @maxAge = 0 AND customerHistory.dateStarted >= @FromDate
                    ) 
                    OR  (
                            customerHistory.dateStarted >= DATEADD(day, -@maxAge, @CurrentDate)
                        )
                )

        UNION

        SELECT
            ''Calendar appointment'' AS ''type''
        ,   ''Calendar appointment'' AS ''categoryType''
        ,   ''Calendar appointment'' AS ''subtype''
        ,   customerAppointmentsAttendees.appointment AS ''guid''
        ,   customerAppointments.StartTime AS ''ActionDate''
        ,   ISNULL((SELECT name FROM userTable WHERE customerAppointments.lastupdatedbyuser = userTable.guid),''system'') AS ''By''
        ,   '''' AS ''Improvement''
        ,   customerAppointments.Description AS ''action''
        ,   customerAppointments.completedNotes AS ''text''
        ,   customerAppointments.timestamp
        ,   0
        ,   0 as ''hasattachment''
        ,   '''' As ''hasBeenLookedAt''
        ,   '''' AS ''IsAvailable''
        ,   ''0'' AS sourceSystem
        ,   '''' AS Categoryids
        ,   '''' AS Duration
        FROM
            customerAppointments
            JOIN customerAppointmentsAttendees on customerAppointmentsAttendees.appointment = customerAppointments.appointment
        WHERE
            customerAppointments.completed = 1
            AND customerAppointmentsAttendees.Attendee = @customer                  
            AND (
                    (
                        @maxAge = 0 AND customerAppointments.StartTime >= @FromDate
                    ) 
                    OR  (
                            customerAppointments.StartTime >= DATEADD(day, -@maxAge, @CurrentDate)
                        )
                )

        UNION

        SELECT 
            ''Accident'' AS type
        ,   ''Accident'' AS subtype
        ,   ''Accident'' AS categoryType
        ,   customerAccident.accident AS ''guid''
        ,   customerAccident.accidentDate AS ActionDate
        ,   ISNULL((SELECT name FROM userTable WHERE customerAccident.lastupdatedbyuser = userTable.guid),''system'') AS ''By''
        ,   '''' as ''Improvement''
        ,   customerAccident.accidentRef 
            + '' - '' + 
            CASE 
                WHEN customerAccident.personalInjury = 1 THEN 
                    ''Injury'' 
                WHEN customerAccident.nearMiss = 1 THEN 
                    ''Near miss'' 
                WHEN customerAccident.propertyDamage = 1 THEN 
                    ''Property damage'' 
                WHEN customerAccident.risk = 1 THEN 
                    ''Risk'' 
            ELSE 
                ''Other'' 
            END AS ''action''
        ,   CAST(customerAccident.injuryNature AS VARCHAR(4096)) AS ''text''
        ,   customerAccident.timestamp
        ,   0
        ,   0 as ''hasattachment''
        ,   '''' As ''hasBeenLookedAt''
        ,   '''' AS ''IsAvailable''
        ,   ''0'' AS sourceSystem
        ,   '''' AS Categoryids
        ,   '''' AS Duration
        FROM
            customerAccident
        WHERE
            customerAccident.customer = @customer                  
            AND (   
                    (
                        @maxAge = 0 AND customerAccident.accidentDate >= @FromDate
                    ) 
                    OR  (
                            customerAccident.accidentDate >= DATEADD(day, -@maxAge, @CurrentDate)
                        )
                )

        UNION

        SELECT
            ''Incident'' AS type
        ,   ''Incident'' AS subtype
        ,   ''Incident'' AS categoryType
        ,   customerIncident.incident AS ''guid''
        ,   customerIncident.incidentDate AS ActionDate
        ,   ISNULL((SELECT name FROM userTable WHERE customerIncident.lastupdatedbyuser = userTable.guid),''system'') AS ''By''
        ,   '''' AS ''Improvement''
        ,   customerIncident.incidentRef + '' - '' + customerIncident.intensity AS ''action''
        ,   CAST(customerIncident.narrative AS VARCHAR(4096)) AS ''text''
        ,   customerIncident.timestamp
        ,   0
        ,   0 AS ''hasattachment''
        ,   '''' As ''hasBeenLookedAt''
        ,   '''' AS ''IsAvailable''
        ,   ''0'' AS sourceSystem
        ,   '''' AS Categoryids
        ,   '''' AS Duration
        FROM
            customerIncident
        WHERE
            customerIncident.person = @customer
            AND (
                    (
                        @maxAge = 0 AND customerIncident.incidentDate >= @FromDate
                    )
                    OR  (
                            customerIncident.incidentDate >= DATEADD(day, -@maxAge, @CurrentDate)
                        )
                )
        ORDER BY 
            ActionDate Desc
        ',N'@customer uniqueidentifier,@FromDate datetime,@FromTimeStamp varbinary(8),@filterText nvarchar(258),@completed int,@completedAndPaid int,@Void int,@Cancelled int,@report nvarchar(9),@CurrentDate datetime,@sign int,@authorised int,@maxAge int',@customer='C661135D-0331-4544-82A7-335C2E7D40AF',@FromDate='2014-10-30 00:00:00',@FromTimeStamp=0x0000000000000000,@filterText=N'%%',@completed=15,@completedAndPaid=18,@Void=17,@Cancelled=20,@report=N'Customer Support',@CurrentDate='2014-11-06 00:00:00',@sign=524,@authorised=21,@maxAge=0
```

The view is cv_customerDailyReport and the tables customerHistory have been indexed. We have run the execution plans and tried to put more indexes based on them but still we are experiencing slowness.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The join count and unions should not be a problem.  As a very basic rule of thumb, you need to make sure that your tables are properly indexed i.e. often used fields in join or filter predicates in your queries should be indexed. If you're already indexed and optimized in other ways then you should consider a reporting db.

Comment: I'd say that the unions and all of those case statements are the issues here.  Id' say a refactoring of the tables to eliminate unions would be a good first step.  And try to normalize the data to avoid all of those case statements.